# Find a polygonal path of minimal length

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

The problem is:

On the plane $XOY$ two points $P_1(a_1,b_1),P_2(a_2,b_2),a_1\geqslant a_2>0,b_2\geqslant b_1>0$ are given. Find such point $Q_1$ on $OX$ axis and point $Q_2$ on $OY$ axis, that the polygonal chain $P_1Q_1Q_2P_2$ has the minimal length.

The answer is known: $|OQ_{1}|=\frac{a_{1}b_{2}-a_{2}b_{1}}{b_{1}+b_{2}},|OQ_{2}|=\frac{a_{1}b_{2}-a_{2}b_{1}}{a_{1}+a_{2}}$, but I don't know how to come to this answer. I tried to minimize the function $f=\sqrt{a_{2}^{2}+(y-b_{2})^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-a_{1})^2+b_{1}^2}$, but I was unable to find any critical points. And I suppose, that checking the sign of $d^2f$ would be even more difficult. Maybe I should take another function, add some conditions and use Lagrange multipliers? Is there any relatively simple analytic solution to this problem?

Comment: The solution posted by @lion is exact, but if you are interested in pushing through the approach of locating critical points, I'll add an answer to address that.

Comment: Please, add one, if you can, and please, don't forget, that after you find critical points, you should check the sign of $d^2f$ for each of them. If $d^2f>0$ for all dx,dy, then we have minimum, if $d^2f<0$ for all dx,dy, then we have maximum and if for some dx, dy $d^2f<0$ and for some dx,dy $d^2f>0$, then we don't have extremum in this point.

Comment: While the second derivative test is *sufficient*, it is not necessary.  There are other ways to prove a critical point is where the function achieves a minimum.

Comment: You can provide another proof, of course. I mean, that it's not sufficient to find critical points, because in a critical point may be a maximum, a minimum or no extremum (saddle point).

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick from physics to this problem. Get the reflection point of $P_1$ w.r.t X-axis as $P_1'$, and the reflection of $P_2$ w.r.t Y-axis as $P_2'$, then you can link $P_1'$ and $P_2'$ by a straight line, which will cross X-axis and Y-axis at two points, which give you the answer.

[image: shortest path by reflected endpoints]

Comment: A picture will help.  If you are agreeable, I will add one.

Comment: @hardmath np, please

Comment: Thank you, a nice trick, I added +1. But I hoped to get the answer using derivatives and/or Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's sketch the proof and then fill in the computational details.

As the OP states, we want to show that for any pair of points $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ in the first quadrant such that:

$$ a_1 \ge a_2 \gt 0 $$

$$ b_2 \ge b_1 \gt 0 $$

the function:

$$ f(x,y) = \sqrt{(x-a_1)^2 + b_1^2} + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{a_2^2 + (y-b_2)^2} $$

attains a *global minimum* at:

$$ x =\frac{a_{1}b_{2}-a_{2}b_{1}}{b_{1}+b_{2}}\;,\; y =\frac{a_{1}b_{2}-a_{2}b_{1}}{a_{1}+a_{2}} $$

**Observations**

Since $a_2$ and $b_1$ are nonzero, $f(x,y) \gt 0$ always.  Note also that if $a_1 = a_2$ and $b_1 = b_2$, the *two* points would coincide.  While this is something of a special case, the conclusion that the global minimum occurs at the point $(x,y)$ given above will still hold.

A further observation can be inserted here for later use.  At first glance there appears to be some symmetry in the roles of $x$ and $y$, but we need to enlarge upon that idea.  What is actually true is that if we interchange $x$ with $y$, $a_1$ with $b_2$, and $a_2$ with $b_1$, then the values of $f(x,y)$ remain unchanged *and* the inequalities on the coordinates $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ are also conserved. This symmetry will come into play in cutting down the amount of computation of derivatives we need below.

**Sketch of proof**

The proof can be considered to have two parts.  First, show that the function $f(x,y)$ does have a global minimum.  This depends on the continuity of $f(x,y)$ and the way it grows "uniformly" to infinity as $(x,y)$ moves away from the origin.

Second, identify the critical points of $f(x,y)$.  Since the global minimum occurs at a critical point, evaluating $f(x,y)$ at it critical points is sufficient to tell us what the minimum is and where it is attained.

---

**A global minimum exists**

Let $r = f(0,0) = \sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}+\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}$.  Then the set $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2 + y^2 \le r^2 \}$ is closed and bounded ([compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space)) in the Euclidean metric.  By the [generalized Extreme Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) for closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we know that $f(x,y)$ attains a minimum value on $D$.

Since the origin $(0,0) \in D$, the minimum value on $D$ must be less than or equal to $f(0,0) = r$.  But for every point $(x,y) \not\in D$, one has (by the definitions of $f(x,y)$ and $D$):

$$ f(x,y) \ge \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \gt r $$

Therefore the minimum value of $f(x,y)$ on $D$ is the global minimum of $f(x,y)$.  This proves the global minimum exists.

---

**Critical points of** $\,\mathbf{f(x,y)}$

One way that a point qualifies as a *critical point* of $f(x,y)$ is by being a *stationary point*, i.e. by having first partial derivatives which "vanish" there (equal zero).  But an alternative kind of critical point is one where the function is defined but the partial derivatives are *undefined*.

We need to concern ourselves in this problem only with the *necessary condition* that says that the point where a global minimum (or equally, a local minimum) occurs must have partial derivatives that are either zero or undefined.  We will see that both possibilities can be realized here.

Taking partial derivatives according to the standard rules gives us these expressions, valid *except* when $(x,y) = (0,0)$:

$$ \begin{align*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &=
\frac{x-a_1}{\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+b_1^2}} + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &=
\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \frac{y-b_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+(y-b_2)^2}} \end{align*} $$

I will leave verification of these expressions to the Readers with the hint that if one of them is verified, the other will follow from interchanging the roles of variables and coordinates mentioned earlier.  What merits a little attention to detail is the question of where these partial derivatives are *undefined*.  It is true that the expressions above are undefined when $(x,y) = (0,0)$, but that is insufficient to show that the partial derivatives do not otherwise exist there.

So let's go back to first principles for one of these, say $f_x$ at $(0,0)$.  We fix the value of $y=0$ in the function definition and simplify:

$$ \begin{align*} f(x,0) &= \sqrt{(x-a_1)^2 + b_1^2} + \sqrt{x^2} + \sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2} \\
&= \sqrt{(x-a_1)^2 + b_1^2} + |x| + \sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2} \end{align*} $$

Only the middle of the three terms poses an obstacle to differentiability.  The final term is a constant (with respect to $x$), and the first term is differentiable at $x=0$.  But $|x|$ is a well known example of how a function can be continuous at $x=0$ but not differentiable there, and so $f_x$ in our problem will not be defined at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.  Similarly (e.g. by the interchange argument) $f_y$ is not defined at the origin.  Therefore the origin is one of the critical points we seek.

Everywhere except at the origin, the first derivatives given by the expressions above are valid and so continuous functions of $x,y$.  Again we will do the work to find where $f_x$ vanishes and appeal by symmetry to get the corresponding condition for $f_y$ vanishing.

Note that:

$$ \begin{align*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 &\iff \frac{x-a_1}{\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+b_1^2}} + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0 \\
&\iff \frac{a_1-x}{\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+b_1^2}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{align*} $$

Before proceeding to further simplify this condition (leading ultimately to a solution), let's observe that equality above requires the numerators $x$ and $a_1-x$ to agree in *sign*.  Since they cannot both be zero (because $a_1 \gt 0$), the only agreement possible is for both to be positive.  Thus:

$$ 0 \lt x \lt a_1 $$

The knowledge of this allows us a bit of flexibility in simplification, because with both numerators *positive*, squaring both sides of the equation does not introduce any extraneous solutions:

$$ \begin{align*} \frac{a_1-x}{\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+b_1^2}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} &\iff \frac{(a_1-x)^2}{(a_1-x)^2+b_1^2} = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \\
&\iff \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2} = \frac{(a_1-x)^2+b_1^2}{(a_1-x)^2} \\
&\iff 1+\frac{y^2}{x^2} = 1+\frac{b_1^2}{(a_1-x)^2} \\
&\iff \frac{y^2}{x^2} = \frac{b_1^2}{(a_1-x)^2} \\
&\iff \frac{y}{x} = \frac{b_1}{(a_1-x)} \end{align*} $$

Let's pause to justify the last step of taking square roots on both sides.  Previously we pointed out that the solution must satisfy $0 \lt x \lt a_1$, so that both $x$ and $a_1-x$ are strictly positive.  When the roles of $x$ and $y$ are interchanged (along with the roles of the coordinates), then the parallel deduction is that $0 \lt y \lt b_2$.  This empowers the deduction that square roots can be taken because both $x,y$ are positive (as are $b_1$ and $a_1-x$).

We continue:

$$ \begin{align*} \frac{y}{x} = \frac{b_1}{(a_1-x)} 
&\iff \frac{a_1-x}{x} = \frac{b_1}{y} \\
&\iff \frac{a_1}{x} - \frac{b_1}{y} = 1 \end{align*} $$

Correspondingly when $x,y$ are interchanged, $a_1,b_2$ are interchanged, and $a_2,b_1$ are interchanged, we get the conclusion:

$$ \frac{-a_2}{x} + \frac{b_2}{y} = 1 $$

Taken together these conditions give a $2\times 2$ linear system to solve for $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{y}$.  Using the familiar form of matrix inverse for the $2\times 2$ case:

$$ \begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{x} \\ \frac{1}{y} \end{pmatrix} &= 
\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & -b_1 \\ -a_2 & b_2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1} \begin{pmatrix} b_2 & b_1 \\ a_2 & a_1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*} $$

Now reciprocating the solutions for $1/x$ and $1/y$, we get the "other" critical point, the one where the first partial derivatives vanish:

$$ \begin{align*}
x &= \frac{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}{b_1 + b_2} \\
y &= \frac{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}{a_1 + a_2} \end{align*} $$

Note that the restrictions on coordinates $a_1 \ge a_2 \gt 0$ and $b_2 \ge b_1 \gt 0$ imply that the numerator shared by $x,y$ above is nonnegative.  Indeed if equality holds in both conditions, then $x=y=0$ (and conversely).

We know that $f(0,0) = \sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2} + \sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}$.

It remains only to evaluate $f(x,y)$ at the other critical point and make the comparison.  Whichever is smaller, that value is our global minimum.

Some algebra is left to do, but no second derivatives will be required.  The comparison of function values comes down to this [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality):

$$ \sqrt{(a_1+a_2)^2+(b_1+b_2)^2} \le \sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}+\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2} $$